# CSS problem in Ask Question on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

I found these little CSS problems on Stack Overflow (red bordered).

Comment: [You could just link to the page, you know.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?)  Give everyone a chance to experience it firsthand.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a couple of CSS class issues.

- `.module` doesn't have any top padding.  Changing that to 10px made the appearance look a lot nicer.
- The button's a bit fiddlier.  `.search-button` is changing the height of the overall button to 2em; if that's removed, sure the button's a bit bigger, but it lines up nicely with the text in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fix Makoto. I have pushed a fix to dev. The change will be on live after the next production build.